# Axodraw drawings and .png images in the same document

Tags: compiling, draw, compilation-error, axodraw4j

I want to be able to put .png images in my document and as well drawings with the package axodraw2. The problem is that to draw a picture and see it in the document I have to compile with **LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf + View Pdf** and to see and ordinary .png image I have to compile with **Pdf LaTeX + View Pdf**.

For example, if I write the following things, which includes an image and a drawing with axodraw2

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{axodraw2}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{lightcone}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
\begin{axopicture}(130,150)
\SetColor{Black}
\Text(70,130){\begin{small}$Im\{p^0\}$\end{small}}
\Text(180,30){\begin{small}$Re\{p^0\}$\end{small}}
\Text(45,40){$\times$}
\Text(95,20){$\times$}
\Text(130,90){$\Gamma$}
\Arc[arrow](70,27)(80,0,90)
\Arc[arrow](70,27)(80,90,180)
\Line[arrow](-10,27)(70,27)
\Line[arrow](70,27)(150,27)
\SetWidth{2}
\LongArrow[arrowscale=0.8](70,20)(70,120)
\LongArrow[arrowscale=0.8](-20,30)(160,30)
\end{axopicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And try to compile with **Pdf LaTeX + View Pdf** I get (the drawing should appear below the image but only the letters that are in the drawing appear)

[image]

If I doesn't include the image and I compile with **LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf + View Pdf** I get the drawing with axodraw2 right

[image]

And including both and trying to compile with **LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf + View Pdf** yields and error message

[image]

Is there a way to include .png images and use axodraw drawings in the same document? I would really appreciate some help. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: No, what I did was transform every .png image in .eps or .ps. Axodraw then runs normally.

Comment: first time hear about ‘axopicture’. Is it better than TikZ?

Comment: Never used this program.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see the `axodraw` manual section 4.3.3.

By running an auxiliary program, similar to the way you run BibTeX or Biber for bibliographies, you can use `axodraw2` with `pdflatex`. The compilation sequence becomes

```
pdflatex filename
axohelp filename
pdflatex filename
```

I think it should be possible to run `axohelp` from Texmaker (User -> User commands), but I couldn't make it work. But running from a terminal should work.

Comment: When I write axohelp it appears command not found, but I have axohelp.exe in my folder. Am I doing right? I haven't much experience with the ubuntu terminal.

Comment: @Slayer147 Ehm, I'd expect that `axohelp` was installed along with the `axodraw2` package in TeX Live, you shouldn't need to manually place an executable somewhere (I didn't at least). I'd also expect that a `.exe` file was a Windows executable, don't know if it would work on Linux.  (I've never used `axodraw`/`axohelp` before, I just opened the manual, found the section I referred to, and tested it successfully with your example, so I don't really know much about it. Personally I'd use TikZ for a diagram like that.)

Comment: I download this files for axodraw2 https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/axodraw2

Comment: For Ubuntu, if you downloaded the files manually, you also need to create the executable manually (the `axohelp.exe` file is only for Windows and does not work in Ubuntu). See the `INSTALL` file on CTAN (i.e., the link you mentioned) for instructions.

Comment: Note that, instead of downloading manually from CTAN, it is easier to install packages using the TeX Live package manager, called `tlmgr`, or using Ubuntu packages with `apt` (see e.g. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=texlive&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all for a list). That takes care of package installing, dependencies, search paths etc.

Comment: I think the problem is that I need to compile the axohelp.c file, but typing the given commands (for example, **gcc -o axohelp -Wall -O3 axohelp.c**) doesn'to do nothing.

Comment: Trying to compile axohelp.c gives me a lot of errors like axohelp.c:(.text+0x17fb): undefined reference to `sqrt'
/tmp/ccbAyYFj.o: In function `ArcSegment':
axohelp.c:(.text+0x1911): undefined reference to `tan'
axohelp.c:(.text+0x1944): undefined reference to `cos'
axohelp.c:(.text+0x1960): undefined reference to `sin'
axohelp.c:(.text+0x19d0): undefined reference to `cos'
axohelp.c:(.text+0x19ec): undefined reference to `sin'
/tmp/ccbAyYFj.o: In function `LengthBezier':
axohelp.c:(.text+0x2650): undefined reference to `sqrt'
axohelp.c:(.text+0x2722): undefined reference to `sqrt'

Comment: @Slayer147 Debugging things like that is beyond me, I can't help there. As Marjin said though, it's usually better to install packages via a package manager. I never had to compile axohelp because a compiled version was part of the installation of TeX Live (which I installed following https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/, more or less).

Comment: @Slayer147 those errors look like a problem with finding libraries, this is a rather complex topic which is out of scope for this site. You could search on Stack Overflow for 'c undefined reference to' it you feel like spending more time on it. On topic: there is an alternative solution to first compile the the axodraw figure with LaTeX-dvips-ps2pdf as a `standalone` document, and then include that pdf with `\includegraphics` in your main document (which is probably more or less what `axohelp` will do for you automatically).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will try this week to do the installation with TeX Live as mentioned in the previous comments. If it works I will close the post. Regards.